# I'm receiving an attribute error when trying to disable a cell in tkCalendar using coordinates

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

My code to disable the date cells on tkCalendar is as follows:

```
from tkcalendar import Calendar
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def dates_play(self,date_entry):
        #Creating the calendar display
        self.cal_display = Calendar(self, selectmode = "day",date_pattern="mm-dd-yyyy", disableddaybackground="red")

        #Placing the widget in a way that it fills up the cell W+E+N+S
        self.cal_display.grid(row=1, rowspan=8,column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W+E+N+S, padx=10, pady=10)
        
        #Converts the date into a date_time object
        date_entry =datetime.strptime(date_entry, "%m-%d-%Y")

        # Retruning the day of the week as a number(X)
        day_no=date_entry.weekday()

        #Returing the week of the month as a number(Y)
        month_no = date_entry.isocalendar()[1]- date_entry.replace(day=1).isocalendar()[1]

        #Disabling that date
        self.cal_display = self.cal_display._calendar[month_no][day_no].state(['disabled'])
```

Error:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Documents\Amm_Uni\BOE Leave Management App\BOE_Leave_Management.py", line 339, in <module>
    app = LeaveBookingApp()
  File "c:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Documents\Amm_Uni\BOE Leave Management App\BOE_Leave_Management.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.create_widgets()
  File "c:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Documents\Amm_Uni\BOE Leave Management App\BOE_Leave_Management.py", line 65, in create_widgets
    self.confirm_button = tk.Button(self, text="Confirm", bg="#a6db9c", width=21, height=2, font= 'Times 15', command = self.dates_play("08-25-2023"))
  File "c:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Documents\Amm_Uni\BOE Leave Management App\BOE_Leave_Management.py", line 320, in dates_play
    self.cal_display = self.cal_display[day_no][month_no].state(['dsiabled'])
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tkcalendar\calendar_.py", line 514, in __getitem__
    raise AttributeError("Calendar object has no attribute %s." % key)
AttributeError: Calendar object has no attribute 4.`
```

I want the dates to be disabled i.e, they will turn grey and the user cannot select them.

Comment: The error is:  raise AttributeError("Calendar object has no attribute %s." % key)
AttributeError: Calendar object has no attribute 4.

Comment: Please remove the screenshot, it's unnecessary. Add the error message along with the full traceback to the quesiton (as text in a code block, not an image).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71900210/how-to-disable-a-date-cell-in-tkcalendar it says there's no built-in way to disable a date

Comment: @Barmar in that one, they've created a new class but I dont want to do that. I want to create a function that does that. I've tried a similar thing using the coordinates, maybe I need to create an array with the tkCalendar? If so, not sure how to do that, help would be appreciated!

Comment: And I want a pony, but I'm not going to get that, either. They created a new class because the existing class doesn't provide a way to do it.

Comment: Anyway, the error is because you can't use `self.cal_display[4]`. A Calendar is not accessible like a list. BTW, you misspelled `disabled`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Any ideas how I can solve the error?

Comment: Sorry, I have absolutely no idea. I found that other question by googling "tkcalendar disable date", that's all I know about the subject.

Comment: No worries, just wondering how did they do it in that example: self._calendar[mi][mj].state(['disabled'])

Comment: `self._calendar` is the internal list that holds all the dates. You could use `self.cal_display._calendar[day_no][month_no]`

Comment: Just be aware that it could potentially break if you upgrade tkcalendar. Attributes beginning with `_` are intended to be internal only. But the same is true of that subclass.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was very useful. Got it to work but now something wrong with the coordinates. For 08-25-2023 it shows 08-31-2023. Any ideas on this too?

Comment: The x coordinate is fine, but Y is incorrect. Adding +1 or -1 to  month_no = date_entry.isocalendar()[1]- date_entry.replace(day=1).isocalendar()[1] moves it along x axis, how can i move it up by one

Comment: Solved it! Had to swap it round: self.cal_display = self.cal_display._calendar[month_no][day_no].state(['disabled']) I'll edit the code above

Comment: Now that you've figured it out, you can answer your own question.

Comment: The disabled ones should be red but its not doing that to the current date selection. E.g if today is the 3rd the calendar selects 3rd when it loads up and if the start_date starts with that, it doesn't get coloured red but gets disabled. How can I fix that please?

Answer (score 0):

As `self._calendar` is the internal list that holds all the dates, I had to add in `._calendar`:

```
self.cal_display._calendar[day_no][month_no]
```